# Progress bas с помощью Intersection Observer

Tags: javascript, progress-bar, observer, intersection-observer

Помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать **Reading Progress Bar** на **Intersection Observer**. Я очень много искал в интернете, но ничего не нашел, большинство примеров были с использованием "scroll". Прогресс бар должен быть написан только с помощью Intersection Observer, без использования window.onscroll и/или "scroll".

В моем коде рассчитывается длина прогресс бара, но там есть ошибка (показывает около 108% вместо 100), не знаю как сделать правильно. И что нужно сделать, чтобы аннимировать progress bar?

```
const mainElement = document.querySelector('.main_content');
const progressBarTop = document.querySelector('.with-progress-reading-bar');
const percentageOfElement = Math.floor((mainElement.scrollHeight / document.body.scrollHeight) * 100);

const options = {
    threshold: 0
};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(function (entries, observer) {
    entries.forEach(entry => {

        let heightOfVP = window.innerHeight;
        let heightOfElement = entry.target.getBoundingClientRect().height;
        let progressPercentage = 0;

        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            progressPercentage = Math.round((window.scrollY / (heightOfElement - heightOfVP)) * percentageOfElement);

            progressBarTop.style.width = progressPercentage + '%';
        }
    })
}, options);

observer.observe(mainElement);
```

Comment: Может быть надо ввести какую то переменную где будет цифра с максимальным значением то в условии мы проверяем и если значение равно длине окружности или длине какого то элемента то остановить высчитование

Comment: @Айболит а как быть с анимацией? Потому что при скролинге она не работает. Только если скролить и обновлять страницу, тогда прогресс бар изменит свое положение

Comment: если вас устррит то я скину пример на jQuery

Comment: @Айболит буду вам благодарен

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/zYoywex  вот смотрите - это надо ?